# In a key value pair how to print out a value that isn't null JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, key-value

So in an example like this I'm trying to print out the names that don't have null in the 'information'

```js
let files = [
{
  name: 'untitled',
  information: null
},
{
  name: 'folder'
  information: 'has storage'
},
{
  name: 'new folder',
  information: 'has 42 items'
},
```

The code that I've been trying to use is this one but it doesn't work when I'm trying to print out the names of the folders that don't have null

```js
let info = files.filter((a) => {
  if (a.information !== null )
  return a
  });
  
  console.log(info)
```

When i put `console.log(info.length)` to see if it's actually taking in, how many of the items don't have the null in it. It does count the items but when I try to see if I can print out their names it only prints `undefined`

is there another way to do this?

Comment: So why don't you check your `information` key at all? Like `const info = files.sort(a => a.information !== null)`?

Comment: Wait, that's now a very different question to what I answered...

Comment: And now I'm confused what the problem is - your code *works*. Or should work - it correctly filters stuff. Yet you claim it's printing `undefined` - when? What are you doing to get that, because THAT would be the code with the problem.

Comment: it works but what i've been trying to do is simply print out the names of each folder that doesn't have null.

Comment: But *how* are you trying to print that? Again, the filter works, you get the correct output out of it. If you're seeing `undefined` it's not related to the code you've posted.

Comment: i guess i've been trying to print it as `console.log(info.name)`

Comment: Your code work correctly but you  need to loop through `info` http://jsfiddle.net/6vk0xoeq/

Answer (score 0):

`filter` return an array , if you want to print the name you again need to iterate over the array

```js
let files = [{
    name: 'untitled',
    information: null
  },
  {
    name: 'folder',
    information: 'has storage'
  },
  {
    name: 'new folder',
    information: 'has 42 items'
  }
]

let info = files.filter((a) => {
  return a.information !== null;
}).forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.name)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the name of the folders. Use map to extract just that, as seen below:

```js
let files = [{
    name: 'untitled',
    information: null
  },
  {
    name: 'folder',
    information: 'has storage'
  },
  {
    name: 'new folder',
    information: 'has 42 items'
  }
]

let info = files.filter((a) => {
  return a.information !== null;
}).map((item)=> {
// Get only the names of the folder
  return item.name;
});

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code if it helps.

```
       let files = [
        {
          name: 'untitled',
          information: null
        },
        {
          name: 'folder'
          information: 'has storage'
        },
        {
          name: 'new folder',
          information: 'has 42 items'
        };

    var getFilesWithInfo = function () {
        var array = [];
        for(var i=0; i<files.length;i++){
           if(files[i].information){
             array.push(files[i]
          }
          return array;
        }
    }

console.log(getFilesWithInfo());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two simple steps with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const files = [{
    name: 'untitled',
    information: null
  },
  {
    name: 'folder',
    information: 'has storage'
  },
  {
    name: 'new folder',
    information: 'has 42 items'
  }
];

const fileNames = files
  .filter(f => f.information !== null)
  .map(f => f.name);

console.log(fileNames);
```